# The USE PLAN hint is not supported for queries that reference external tables

Tags: sql, azure, azure-analysis-services

I have an Azure Analysis Service that is getting data from a Azure SQL Database every 3 minutes. I was working fine but suddenly it start failing with the error:

> The USE PLAN hint is not supported for queries that reference external tables

It is just getting information from a View and we are not using query hints, but we do are getting information from an external table that is making reference to another database. Do you have any idea why this can happen? It just start failing this morning.

This is the code in Azure Analysis Service:

```
let
    Source = #"SQL/myserver;mydatabase",
    vw_Dsh_myview = Source{[Schema="dbo",Item="vw_Dsh_myv"]}[Data]
in
    vw_Dsh_myview
```

When I change it to this:

```
let
    Source = Value.NativeQuery(#"SQL/myserver;mydatabase", "SELECT * from vw_Dsh_myview")
in
    Source
```